# Extend Windows 7 Start Menu to do maths

Tags: windows-7

I'm used to tools like Gnome Do in Linux and Spotlight on OSX. These actually do useful things like maths, dictionary and so on. Is there any way to do this in Windows 7? I can't believe they overlooked this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) + [Mathy Resurrected](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mathyresurected/) + other [plugins](http://www.launchy.net/plugins.php) is what you should look it.

[image]

Comment: Pretty much got me what I wanted, except I can't use math functions  to the same extent. *Edit*, appears I was wrong, turning off the calcy plugin lets resurrected do it's job.